# How to/should I bypass switches?

Tags: switches, bypass, dpdt, spdt

I want to make a stage box (with light in it) so when the guitarist or singer steps on it, it lights up. In the box I want to use a 12W (or maybe later 2) LED lights (which have a normal EU power plug).

I want to make initially two means of turning them on:

1. By stepping on the box (on a plateau)
2. By pressing a foot pedal

The reason is that I don't know if I can make option 1 very reliable, so option 2 is a backup.

Also since both options might fail, I want to use rocker toggle switches to bypass both options (meaning if both rocker switches are ON/bypass, the light should always light up).

I changed the answer to use a relay (instead of using mains, as of the comment of MrGerber below).

[image: After update]

I had the following circuit in mind, but I wonder:

- If it is a good way to bypass this way
- If for the foot bypass switch, I really need a DPDT switch (I couldn't find any other way).
- If I need another way as the relay.

(actually the 12W Led lamp is inserted with a normal power EU 220V plug, but I couldn't find a symbol for this).

Comment: Quite frankly, I would not have my guitarist or vocalist step on something that is fabri-cobbled together and connected to mains voltage.

Comment: @MrGerber What is a better way? using a relais and low power?

Comment: If you're not completely sure about how to make something and how to make it in a safe manner, I would say a better way is to look for something OTS. <br>

Comment: @MrGerber If I would be completely sure, I wouldn't have to ask. On youtube videos can be found (without the bypass/foot switches but with the plateau switch), but I want to make it more reliable. But please provide at least some ideas to make it more safe. I could use a relay (probably that would make it both safe, and also I don't have to worry about too much current going through the switches).

Comment: A guitarist asks: What's a plateau switch? What do you mean by "box"? Why would either method fail? Finally, do it all with 9V. Surely almost every guitarist has a 9V wall wart on stage?

Comment: @Dibosco it's a switch that is on the top of the box (the 'plateau' )... it's not an electrical term. It would fail because it has to be mounted under the plateau (with pressure). If it gets loose somehow than it does not work anymore. I need 220V anyway for the LED lamp, but I can  use even a simple OTS adapter to get 5V or 9V. The stage boxes will not necessarily be near the guitarist.

Comment: Instead of assuming that the switch will come loose, secure it properly the first time. Then you won't have to do the job twice, and the end product will be simpler, more reliable, and less crappy overall. If the pressure mounting system that you allude to won't cut it, use a different mounting system that will.

Comment: I have to agree with @Dampmaskin. Back in the early 90s I designed myself a couple of foot switches for use on stage including one with that really heavy duty metal plunger and round bit on the top and that still works fine. There's absolutely no reason why a switch should fail if it's put together well. As far as "needing" 220V for the LED lamp, I don't get this, LEDs run from a far smaller voltage and some are really bright these days. There is really no reason to need mains on the foot switch. Honest, guv :)

Comment: @Dampmaskin I hope I can do that ... the way I checked on youtube is that felt is used, and I wonder if felt stays in place, it's a matter of millimeters/inches. Or I should search for a pressure sensor instead.

Comment: @DiBosco See also above comment ... the 220 V LED Lamp is a OTS lamp that contains of an enclosure with 36 LED lights with DMX controller builtin.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see now and I see you've modified the schematic. A relay looks better. Still think you only need one switch though. Is this going to be switched on and off a lot?

Comment: @DiBosco ... I will remove the bypass switch. Actually I don't know yet how often it will be switched on, but not in terms of seconds. Actually my assumption is like 10 times per hour, max, with an average of 30 seconds each time, but possibly longer. So if you are asking it for the relais, it should not be any problem.

Comment: @DiBosco I created an answer with your advise, thanks!

Comment: I think that's on and off quite a lot. I don't know the answer to this for definite, but wonder whether a triac rather than a relay might be better for this. Hopefully one of the plethora of power experts here would confirm or deny this.

Comment: @DiBosco I thought relays can easily handle hundred of switch moments per hour (if needed). I would have to check what a triac is (I heard of it, but that's about it).

Comment: Yeah, they can, but they are mechanical devices which are less reliable than electronic devices. Have a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/triac-versus-relay   Triacs aren't hard to use. A relay will certainly work here, don't get me wrong. :)

Comment: @DiBosco I will check it, thanks ... I saw a 'random' datasheet where the lifetime of relay switches is from 10,000 to 250,000. My Chinese ones might be on the low side, but still, 10,000 is a lot of switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one (or all) of the switches should turn on the lights, just connect all the switches in parallel.  No need to take any switch out-of-circuit, unless you expect it to fail "On".

Comment: It's not that simple, because it's like on/off switches, like one press: on, next press off. Like two switches being able to switch the same lamp in a house.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: what you are using are commonly called "alternate action switch" - that wasn't clear to me from your original post.  If you are using alternate action switches, then you will have to remove the unwanted switches from the circuit, and simply paralleling switches won't work.

Comment: ok, I will have to check into this further, just for my understanding, an alternate action switch is the same as a lock switch or toggle switch? And a 'simple?'action switch is the same as a lockless switch or momentary switch?

Comment: An alternate action switch would be a "push-on/push-off" pushbutton, while a normal pushbutton would be push-on/release off.  A toggle switch is operated by a lever, rather than a pushbutton (my terminology - others may vary)

Comment: Ok, in that case the plateau-switch should be normal push button and the floor switch an alternate action switch :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would put the plateau on 4 springs. One contact under the plateau, the other on the frame of the box. 3mm between the two contacts, aka "the switch". When the guitarist steps on, the springs get pressed and the contacts get closed. If the springs can be pressed with 1/10 of the weight of a person, the switch will be reliable IMO. 
It's a good idea to use a relay. It allows you connect whatever device you want. 
I would use 9 or 12V to power the coils of the relay. 5V is less reliable. Make sure the connection is either 100% off or 100% on mecanicaly and that contacts are never slightly touching each other.

Comment: Yes also thought about the springs, but I'm not so handy with the 'hardware' part and the guy who wants to make it says springs are not 'needed'. The plateau is a metal grate/grill with holes, so a spring might be harder to attach.
Probably I can add a 9V adapter (from 220V).

Comment: You can use very small springs, just enough to keep the plateau 3 mm above the contact. You can also use laser sensors or other sensors, but it's more complicated IMO, electronicaly than spring switches.

Comment: I would have to check into that, thanks, on a YouTube video I saw somebody using weather strips (to put to windows/doors), which seem very easy to attach/glue.

Answer (score 0):

After DiBosco's comment to remove the bypass switches (and my idea to add an Always On switch instead, and remove the floor switch):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxmWzA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This answers all my questions, although the functionality is different than requested, but probably better (if I can make the plateau switch very reliable).